# scala: what does |, &, as means?

Tags: scala

I stumbled upon those three `word/operator?/things`: `|`, `&` and `as` while reading some code and google doesn't help much to gather information regarding their meaning.

So, what are they?

Here are some sample where I found them:

```
def |[R >: L <: HList](that: Directive[R]): Directive[R] =
    recover(rejections ⇒ directives.BasicDirectives.mapRejections(rejections ::: _) & that)

def &(magnet: ConjunctionMagnet[L]): magnet.Out = magnet(this)

def as[T](deserializer: HListDeserializer[L, T]): thing1[T] =
    new thing1[T] {
      def do(f: T :: HNil ⇒ Route) =
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this particular example, these mean nothing special and are just simple method names as any other.

Comment: For a more precise explanation, could you say in which lib you have found those ? As @SarveshKumarSingh said, these are valid names for methods, and can mean whatever the implementor wanted them to mean.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet this is probably from Spray source code.

Comment: it is from spray source code, thanks, I am so used for those to be special operator...

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, I was indeed thinking about `akka-http`. The aim of my question was mainly to understand if the OP question was about the fact that these methods have unusual names (say, for java developers), or what they do in the particular context in which they want to use them.

Comment: I thought they were special operator like in C, java, etc but no, they just are method name... Thanks a lot.